# Convert a filter from NHibernate to Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate

There is a method in my application which returns entities filtering by a property from result set in the system like this

```
IList<T> GetByProperty(string name, object value);
```

The method uses `Restrictions` to create a criteria, it looks like

```
var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<T>();
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq(name, value));
return criteria.List<T>();
```

With EF, I see we can use `Where` to filter by a specified property such as

```
posts.Where(p => p.Title.Contains("XYZ"))
```

My question: is it possible to use property **Title** in a dynamically way, to accept the property given in `name` parameter? Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the name variable you mention in place of the constant string.

Comment: do you have any example, please? @daf

Comment: O hang on. I read your question incorrectly. My prior answer is rubbish ): if I were at a desktop, I could figure this out for you, but I'm unfortunately away from home, on a tablet. You could construct an appropriate LINQ expression using reflection on your Post POCO and pass that into the Where method. Sorry I'm not much help right now.